# jQuery-UI DateTimePicker doesn't work

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I'm needing to develop a datetimepicker Input with jquery-ui. I already developed a datepicker, and the same is working perfectly. The problem is that the DateTimePicker is displaying a datepicker, so the choice of missing time.

Below the function with the DatePicker that is working properly:

```
function initInputDate() {

    //Regionaliza o datepicker


    //Seleciona todos os Inputs de Data
    $("*").on("focus", ".inputData", function() {

        $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional[ "pt-BR" ]);

        //Adiciona o plugin datepicker do JQuery-UI aos inputs de data
        $(this).datepicker({
            showAnim: 'slideDown',
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true
        });


    });

}
```

This function below is what is wrong. She is displaying a DatePicker, but should display a DateTimePicker. I've realized that the DateTimePicker displayed is different from that shown in the above function, ie they are compoentes different because I removed the buttons, but they appear in this function below to false DateTimePicker.

```
function initInputDateTime() {

    //Seleciona todos os Inputs de Data
    $("*").on("focus", ".inputDataHora", function() {

        //Adiciona o plugin datepicker do JQuery-UI aos inputs de data
        $(this).datetimepicker({
            showAnim: 'slideDown',
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true
        });

    });

}
```

I've cared properly scripts:

```
jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js
jquery.js
jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.js
```

This image display the wrong datepicker it must be a datetimepicker:

The HTML of the input:

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <b>Data e Hora da Análise:* </b>
  </td>
  <td>
    <input id="dsAnalise" class="input inputDataHora hasDatepicker" type="text" size="15" maxlength="16" value="" name="dsAnalise">
  </td>
</tr>
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you try it by changing the order of JS files: 
1. jquery.js 2. jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.js 3. jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js ?

Comment: Yes, I change after and now.

Comment: @mayconfsbrito Could you please show something of your HTML markup that you use. Right now it is blind guessing what might not work and why.
I guess that both functions are called?!

Comment: So, I've posted the html above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solve the problem. The solution was to replace some scripts like jquery-ui.min.js and the reorganization of the same, as in  I have a script called main.js other scripts running javascript / jquery.

Below I display the organization of scripts:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/fwsibe/sistema/libraries/interface/javascript/jquery/lib/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/fwsibe/sistema/libraries/interface/javascript/jquery/lib/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/fwsibe/assets/jquery/js/jquery-ui-sliderAccess.js"></script>
```

Here I display the main.js file that initializes the scripts:

```
    var dirJquery = "/fwsibe/sistema/libraries/interface/javascript/jquery/";
    var dirJqueryPlugins = dirJquery + "plugins/";
    var dirScriptsEvento = dirJquery + "scripts/eventos/";
    var dirJqueryUi = dirJquery + "lib/jquery-ui/";
    var arrayScripts = new Array(
        dirJqueryPlugins + "datepicker/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js",
        dirScriptsEvento + "Menu.js",
        dirScriptsEvento + "Dialog.js",
        dirScriptsEvento + "Button.js",
        dirScriptsEvento + "Template.js",
        dirScriptsEvento + "Select.js",
        dirScriptsEvento + "InputDate.js",
        dirJqueryPlugins + "jquery.maskedinput.min.js",
        dirJqueryPlugins + "jquery.ba-replacetext.min.js",
        dirJqueryPlugins + "jquery.ba-hashchange.min.js",
        dirJqueryPlugins + "jquery.form.min.js",
        dirJqueryPlugins + "fancybox/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"
        );
$(function() {

    //Carrega os scripts JQuery
    loadScripts();

});

/**
 * Recarrega os scripts de evento jQuery sempre que um determinado evento acontece
 */
function loadScripts() {

    for (var i = 0; i < arrayScripts.length; i++) {
        jQuery.getScript(arrayScripts[i]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is absolutely wrong. Both datepicker and datetimepicker need only to be initiated once for each field, not on each focus. They are getting displayed from themselves, you don't have to do anything there.

So to correct that, the resulting code would be as following:

```
function initInputDate() {

    $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional[ "pt-BR" ]);
    $('.inputDataHora').datepicker({
            showAnim: 'slideDown',
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true
    });    
}


function initInputDateTime() {

    //Seleciona todos os Inputs de Data
    $(".inputData").datetimepicker({
            showAnim: 'slideDown',
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true
    });

}
```

Then the jQuery JS files should be added in this order:

```
jquery.js
jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.js
jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js
```

Comment: I belive that  must be related to the fact that I'm using ajax, and therefore the need .on();

Comment: Where do you use AJAX? How is it connected with this?

Comment: The components are dynamically loaded, so I have to use the function .on() several times. Otherwise they are not loaded.

Comment: If you already use on for dynamically loaded components, than attach it to one element that is already there from the beginning and let it only execute on delegated events from the affected dynamically loaded elements. See [delegated events](http://api.jquery.com/on/) in the documentation of on().

Comment: I deleguei function, but nothing happened. The problem remains the same. $("*").on("focus", ".inputDataHora", function() {
        $(this).datetimepicker({
            showAnim: 'slideDown',
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true
        });

    });